# How do I convert System::Int64^ to std::int64_t (c++)?

Tags: c++, winforms

I have tried using marshal_as (code below), but it does not support this type of conversion. I have tried researching the solution but could not find one.

```
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>

std::int64_t stdNum = marshal_as<std::int64_t>(sysNum);
```

Comment: Do you actually need a `System::Int64^`? `System::Int64` will be faster and i think directly convertible to c++ numeric types

Comment: Unfortunately yes